# (Java Minecraft 1.14.2) How to make a charged creeper do more damage without increasing explosion radius or summoning multiple?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm writing a datapack with the [Holy Hand Grenade of Antioch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QM9Bynjh2Lk) from *Monty Python and the Holy Grail*. I have everything working, (see [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/350841/java-minecraft-1-14-how-to-detect-when-a-spash-potion-explodes-and-its-posit) post) but I'd like to make the charged creeper I spawn in do more damage but with a smaller explosion radius. I know giving mobs strength makes them hit harder, but creepers don't hit per se, they just explode, so that doesn't seem like it would work (correct me if I'm wrong). Here is my command to spawn it in:

```
summon creeper ~ ~ ~ {Fuse:0,powered:1,Invulnerable:1,ExplosionRadius:1.5,CustomName:"\"a Holy Hand Grenade of Antioch\""}
```

I know that creepers' explosions deal damage to entities and having multiple creepers will add that damage together, but it also destroys any drops so I don't want to go that route. Is there a way to increase the damage for the creeper without making it's explosion radius any bigger or spawning in multiple creepers?

Be aware that I have this in a function which turns mobgriefing off right before summoning the creeper and turns it back on right after the creeper explodes. The concern isn't making bigger craters but making the area that it effects too large so the thrower is impacted (it's a potion so it can't be thrown super far).

Comment: Yes, I have the perfect solution! I can't write down the complete command right now, because I'm not at a computer, but creepers can be "charged" with potion effects since 1.13. When they die while having a potion effect (and I think this includes exploding), they leave behind an AreaEffectCloud of that potion effect. You could just make this a very high level of instant damage and it should probably work, because I assume you make the creeper explode instantly. If that doesn't work, use wither. An alternative solution would be not to use a creeper at all, but instead just having the thrown …

Comment: … potion itself be an instant damage potion and just simulate the explosion with the particle and sound. Except if you also want the visible knockback, that makes it much more complicated.

Comment: That sounds like it will work, but I'm using the charged creeper so players have a way of getting mob heads without me having to modify loot tables. If I 'charge' the creeper with instant damage, and the effect kills the mob, will is still drop the head?

Comment: Probably not. <comment padding>

Comment: But there is a chance the creeper explosion will kill it and a chance the effect will kill it? Because I could just make the ingredients less expensive and have there be an effective drop chance.

Comment: Since you're triggering the creeper yourself, you could just as well make the AreaEffectCloud appear first and give it a very strong poison effect, then make the creeper explode with a slight delay (maybe .1 seconds is already enough).

Comment: Did that comment help you? Should I write it as an answer?

Comment: Yeah I think so. Is this the method of "charging" the creeper: spawning an AreaEffectCloud? Or is that something separate?

Comment: I just noticed that this AreaEffectCloud is useless anyway, you can just give everything in a radius poison (except undead mobs). But what is actually your goal? Do you want everything in a certain zone to die, but nothing outside that zone to get damaged at all? Or should it fall with distance? Also, wouldn't it be an option to just make the items invulnerable?

Comment: My goal is basically to add a potion which when hitting something does damage by summoning a charged creeper, so it also drops mob heads. This damage should be a lot at the origin of where the potion hit (where the creeper is summoned) and drop off to 0 about 6 blocks away. I suppose that after each creeper is summoned I could make all items within 6 blocks invulnerable, however.

Answer (score 1):

You could summon an area effect cloud in the same position as the creeper. This command would do just that:

```
summon minecraft:area_effect_cloud ~ ~ ~ {Potion:"minecraft:strong_harming",Radius:1.5f,Duration:6,Particle:"minecraft:explosion"}
```

If the affected area for this is too large, then you can simply decrease the Radius.