# (Minecraft Java 1.14.4) How do I continuously test if there is air below an entity?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make an explosive snowball, but I need to test if there is air or a block under the snowball. I tried tags so when it is in the air the snowball gets a tag "air":

`/execute as @e[type=minecraft:snowball] at @e[type=minecraft:snowball] if block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:air run tag @s add air`

But I realized it would not remove the tag if the condition was false.

Is there a block name or something I can put in, like `/execute as @e[type=minecraft:snowball] at @e[type=minecraft:snowball] if block ~ ~-1 ~ !minecraft:air run summon tnt ~ ~ ~ {Fuse:0}` ?

Comment: FYI here are two questions related to the subject which might prove helpful to you: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/355871/java-minecraft-1-14-snowball-entity-tag-not-copied-over-for-last-item-in-a https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/350841/java-minecraft-1-14-how-to-detect-when-a-spash-potion-explodes-and-its-posit I asked both of them while basically doing the same thing as you are, so you might find them useful. If you are trying to test for air to determine when to explode the snowball, use the solution from the second question instead.