# Why does my MCPE command not work in MCJE?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm using the following code in MCPE:

```
tp @e[type=husk] @e[type=wolf]
```

Java Edition shows the `@e[type=wolf]` in red.

What is the correct way to write this command?

Comment: Please only write with proper English on StackExchange. I've edited your post to make it more clean.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need to make target selector only select one entity](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/348970/need-to-make-target-selector-only-select-one-entity)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the error message:

```
Only one entity is allowed, but the provided selector allows more than one at position 0: <--[HERE]
```

When only one entity will be accepted, it is *your* job to make sure the target selector returns only one entity. Unlike Bedrock Edition, if your target selector *allows* more than one entity to be selected, *even if it will return only one entity when run*, it throws an error.

You need to use the `limit=1` parameter to limit your target selection to one entity.

```
tp @e[type=husk] @e[type=wolf,limit=1]
```